# Angularjs Splice in Nested Array

Tags: angularjs, nested, dynamicform

Hi can somebody help Removing element from nested json array like this

**JSON**

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Furniture & Fixture",
    "choice": {
        "0": {
            "req_goods": "table",
            "qty": "10"
        },
        "1": {
            "req_goods": "chair",
            "qty": "5"
        }
    }
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Miscellaneous Property",
    "choice": {
        "0": {
            "req_goods": "Office Rent",
            "qty": "1"
        }
    }
}]
```

here how do I remove choice 1 of id 1 .

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="cb in capital_budgets">
    <div ng-repeat="choice in choices[$index]">
        <input ng-model="cb.choice[$index].req_goods">
        <input ng-model="cb.choice[$index].qty">
        <button ng-hide="$first" ng-click="removeChoice($parent.$index,$index)">-</button>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="addNewChoice($index)">+</button>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.capital_budgets = [{"id":1,"name":"Furniture & Fixture"},
                          {"id":2,"name":"Miscellaneous Property"}];
    $scope.choices = [{}];
    $scope.choices[0] = [{}];
    $scope.choices[1] = [{}];
    $scope.choices[2] = [{}];
    $scope.choices[3] = [{}];
    $scope.choices[4] = [{}];

    $scope.addNewChoice = function(id) {
        $scope.choices[id].push({});
    };

    $scope.removeChoice = function(parent_id, id) {
        $scope.choices[parent_id].splice(id, 1);
    };
```

The Above removeChoice() remove last element but I want to remove the element that user choose to remove. please help i have been trying from 2 days.

Comment: You have different data structures in your question, which one is correct? With nested objects or arrays? `arr.splice(1,2)` works with arrays, `delete obj.field` works with objects.

Comment: i am new to angularjs. i don't have much idea.i just want to remove element (0:req_good and qty) of let say 'Furniture & Fixture' from above json. Please can you show me a different data structures of above json and also how to make them of same structure. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make 'choice' of the array type as follows and use the index of the particular choice in the `ng-repeat` directive to remove the choice from the choices array.

```js
angular
  .module('demo', [])
  .controller('DefaultController', DefaultController);
  
  function DefaultController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.items = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Furniture & Fixture",
        "choices": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "req_goods": "table",
          "qty": "10"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "req_goods": "chair",
          "qty": "5"
        }]
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Miscellaneous Property",
        "choices": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "req_goods": "Office Rent",
          "qty": "1"
        }]
    }];
    
    vm.removeChoice = removeChoice;
    vm.addChoice = addChoice;
    
    function removeChoice(itemId, index) {
      for (var i = 0; i < vm.items.length; i++) {
        if (vm.items[i].id === itemId) {
          vm.items[i].choices.splice(index, 1);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    
    function addChoice(index) {
      var id = vm.items[index].choices.length + 1;
      vm.items[index].choices.push({
        id: id,
        req_goods: "",
        qty: 0
      });
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo">
  <div ng-controller="DefaultController as ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items">
      <h3>{{item.name}}</h3>
      <div ng-repeat="choice in item.choices">
        <input type="text" ng-model="choice.req_goods" />
        <input type="text" ng-model="choice.qty" />
        <button type="button" ng-click="ctrl.removeChoice(item.id, $index)">Remove</button>
      </div>
      <button type="button" ng-click="ctrl.addChoice($index)">Add</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you. one more question please how do i push a new array to choices

Comment: @sanu check the update, you can learn the basics of AngularJS from this course https://www.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js it is good for beginners

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 $scope.removeChoice = function(parent_id,id) {       

    var TempArr=[];
    var parentLength=$scope.choices[parent_id].length;
    for(i=0;i<parentLength;i++ ){
        if(parentLength[i]!==id){
            TempArr.push(parentLength[i]);
        }
        if(i==parentLength-1){
             $scope.choices[parent_id]=[];
            $scope.choices[parent_id]=TempArr;
        }
    }
 };
```

Comment: Add $scope.choices[parent_id]=[];  before   $scope.choices[parent_id]=TempArr; this and the check

Answer (score 0):

You can remove choice "1" of id 1 using the below code snippet.

```js
var json = [
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Furniture & Fixture",
    "choice": {
        "0": {
            "req_goods": "table",
            "qty": "10"
        },
        "1": {
            "req_goods": "chair",
            "qty": "5"
        }
    }
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Miscellaneous Property",
    "choice": {
        "0": {
            "req_goods": "Office Rent",
            "qty": "1"
        }
    }
}];

function removeChoice(json, parentId, choice) {
  for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    if (json[i].id === parentId) {
      delete json[i].choice[choice];
      break;
    }
  }
}

removeChoice(json, 1, "1");
console.log(json);
```

If you want the the choice also to be of the same type as its parent element i.e. an array you could change your JSON as follows and do as shown in the below code snippet to remove a choice from the JSON

```js
var json = [
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Furniture & Fixture",
    "choices": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "req_goods": "table",
      "qty": "10"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "req_goods": "chair",
      "qty": "5"
    }]
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Miscellaneous Property",
    "choices": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "req_goods": "Office Rent",
      "qty": "1"
    }]
}];

function removeChoice(json, parentId, choiceId) {
  for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    if (json[i].id === parentId) {
      for (var j = 0; j < json[i].choices.length; j++) {
       if (json[i].choices[j].id === choiceId) {
          json[i].choices.splice(j, 1);
          break;
        }
      }
      
      break;
    }
  }
}

removeChoice(json, 1, 1);
console.log(json);
```

In both of the above methods I've passed the source you want to modify as a parameter to the `removeChoice` function whereas you can also directly use a variable available within the scope of execution of the `removeChoice` function and pass only `parentId` and `choiceId` as parameters in the below code snippet, you can replace `items` with the object on your controller's `$scope`.If you prefer isolation of the code you can pass the `items` object as a parameter to the `removeChoice` function as it won't be dependent on the external components directly being used in the method body, I would suggest to have separation of concerns.

```js
var items = [
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Furniture & Fixture",
    "choices": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "req_goods": "table",
      "qty": "10"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "req_goods": "chair",
      "qty": "5"
    }]
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Miscellaneous Property",
    "choices": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "req_goods": "Office Rent",
      "qty": "1"
    }]
}];

function removeChoice(parentId, choiceId) {
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].id === parentId) {
      for (var j = 0; j < items[i].choices.length; j++) {
       if (items[i].choices[j].id === choiceId) {
          items[i].choices.splice(j, 1);
          break;
        }
      }
      
      break;
    }
  }
}

removeChoice(1, 1);
console.log(items);
```

Comment: yes i use it like-> delete $scope.capital_budgets[parent_id].choice[id]; it delete the element but won't remove -> <button ng-hide="$first" ng-click="removeChoice($parent.$index,$index)">-</button> like we will do in splice any idea?

Comment: The splice function is used on an Array, are you using an Array for the choice object or a JavaScript object?

Comment: how do i make the choice array type i been trying this  <input ng-model="cb.choice[$index].req_goods"> and this i think will make object type please see my above code thank you